# Deploying Worklight Adapter/WLAPP to server with protected console using ANT

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to deploy adapters & WLAPP using ANT to a server with a protected Worklight console  (form-based).
Here's my ANT task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="help">
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="worklight-ant.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="test">
    <adapter-deployer deployable="Test.adapter" worklightServerHost="http://testserver/MyApp" userName="username" password="password" />
</target>
</project>
```

When I run it I got this error message:

```
adapter-deployer doesn't support the "userName" attribute
```

The server is running Worklight 6.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*revised answer:* What you're looking to do is not possible in Worklight 6.0.0.0. It was added as part of the Worklight 6.0.0.1 fix pack release via:

> [PM98052](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM98052)  You cannot deploy with ANT tasks when security is enabled for
>   the Application Center or Console

Make sure you are using the latest Worklight 6.0.0.x fix pack, currently: [Worklight 6.0.0.2 Developer Edition](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.0.0.2.zip) (if you are an IBM customer or business partner, you can get it from Fix Central).

Comment: So it seems to be a documentation issue?, as username/password attributes were explained in V6.0 documentation
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_adapters.html

Comment: Sorry, apparently this was also fixed in 6.0.0.1 fixpack: PM98052 You cannot deploy with ANT tasks when security is enabled for the Application Center or Console

Comment: @MElkady, please mention your exact Worklight version; also mention the type of console protection you've implemented.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help @idan-adar
I'm using Worklight V6.0.0.0 with a form-based protected console.

I'll try to update to 6.0.0.2 & try again